# SELECT fails after insert duplicate key error

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, sqlalchemy

I am running MySQL at its default isolation level (REPEATABLE-READ).

My python code uses sqlalchemy to manage a transaction which can (and is quite often) running at the same time within two concurent processes.

```
c.begin();
# this SELECT establishes the transaction snapshot from which all other SELECTs will read data
c.execute("SELECT something FROM sometable;")
try:
  c.execute("INSERT INTO othertable (unique_key) VALUES (1)")
except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as e:
  code, msg = e.orig
  if code != 1062:
    raise
  # duplicate key: another transaction commited the above INSERT so I can't rely on LAST_INSERT_ID
  rows = c.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE unique_key=1")
  inserted_id = None
  for id, in rows:
    inserted_id = id
    break
  assert inserted_id is not None
else:
  inserted_id = c.last_insert_id()
c.commit()
```

The exact code is obviously a bit more complex with many more queries but the crux of the issue is that this code hits the assert in the exception handler quite often.

The reason is that this transaction is often running at the same time in different processes: the SELECT which is triggered on the duplicate key exception fails because the DB snapshot established by the first SELECT does not contain the newly-inserted row (it was inserted by another transaction after the first SELECT and before the INSERT).

Now, I understand I could change my SELECTs to use FOR UPDATE and that would punch a hole in the snapshot to read the actual value inserted.

However, I am reluctant to do this because it would force me to sprinkle this in quite a few places and I see this as being relatively fragile.

Are there other, more robust, more standard, less fugly ways to deal with these concurent inserts (they are a fact of life that I have to deal with).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an artificial update appears to be sufficient to force mysql to update its transaction snapshot:

```
c.begin();
# this SELECT establishes the transaction snapshot from which all other SELECTs will read data
c.execute("SELECT something FROM sometable;")
try:
  c.execute("INSERT INTO othertable (unique_key) VALUES (1)")
except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as e:
  code, msg = e.orig
  if code != 1062:
    raise
  # duplicate key: another transaction commited the above INSERT so I can't rely on LAST_INSERT_ID
  # ARTIFICAL UPDATE TO FORCE MYSQL TO UPDATE ITS SNAPSHOT
  c.execute("UPDATE table SET value = something WHERE unique_key=1")
  rows = c.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE unique_key=1")
  inserted_id = None
  for id, in rows:
    inserted_id = id
    break
  assert inserted_id is not None
else:
  inserted_id = c.last_insert_id()
c.commit()
```

Note:

1. MariaDB 10.2.9 appears to be happy with *any* UPDATE statement on this row (including value updates that do not change the row values) to trigger the snapshot update
2. MySQL 5.6.28 ignores the snapshot update unless the UPDATE changes the row values somehow